# Insert an animated gif image in a `beamer` presentation

Tags: presentations, animations

I have gif animated image that I want insert in a presentation that I'm building with the `beamer` package. I want that the image is animated also in the presentation and the only way that I know to do that is to isolate the gif images, save them as JPG, than insert the sequence of these images using the `animate` package. But this is a tedious work to do, so I ask if there is some other more quick way .

Comment: Probably not, since Gif is not directly supported by the PDF standard.

Comment: Alternatively convert it to MP4 or SWF and include this using the `media9` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look to the package [movie15](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/) of LATEX.

Be careful, this package is advertised as deprecated on CTAN in favor of the newest [media9](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/media9). The problem is that **media9 does NOT support GIFs** as far as I know and therefore if you want to use a GIF directly in media9 you need to convert it in an available format for the package (i.e. FLV, MP4).

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thank you. I've solved the problem converting the image to .avi an than using the ` \movie` command.

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to help when I can. Buona serata :-)